# Text stretches when citing URL

Tags: bibtex, urls

I am trying to cite a URL, but for some reason it stretches the author and title in a very weird fashion. This is how I include my bibliography:

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{biblio.bib}
```

and this is (one of the) entries I have trouble with:

```
@misc{TDS:Regression/classification,
  title = {Regression or Classification? Linear or Logistic?},
  howpublished = {\url{https://towardsdatascience.com/regression-or-classification-linear-or-logistic-f093e8757b9c}},
  note = {[Online; Accessed: 16-05-2020]},
  author={Taylor Fogarty}
}
```

This gives rise to the following result:

[image]

Can someone help me out here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably the `xurl` can help here.

Comment: It does, thanks a lot!

Comment: And if you don't have access to the `xurl` package, be sure to load the `url` package with the options `hyphens` and `spaces`: `\usepackage[hyphens,spaces]{url}`.

Comment: Whatever else you do, be sure to encase the word `Linear` in curly braces; that way, BibTeX won't convert its to all-lowercase (as is happening in your screenshot).

Comment: Ah, that's a great tip as well! Thank you very much!